# How to handle a post request from an external application in Drupal?

Tags: routes

I am integrating with the Stripe payment gateway and I need to be able to handle a post from their server to authenticate a standalone account. I am trying to follow the instructions at https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts

Namely, I need to provide a callback URL which will receive the data I need through request parameters.

https://mydrupalsite.com/callback?scope=read_write&code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE

I need to be able to get the scope and the code value.

Once I have that, I will need to then redirect based on their values to certain pages.

I tried creating a MENU_CALLBACK type menu item with a page callback to handle the parameters, but what I tried didn't work.
Below is the code I tried.

```
function bh_commerce_stripe_oauth_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['bh_commerce_stripe_oauth/callback/%'] = array(
        'title' => 'bh_commerce_stripe_oauth_callback',
        'page callback' => '_bh_commerce_stripe_oauth_handle_callback',
        'page arguments' => array(2),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK     
  );
  return $items;    
}


function _bh_commerce_stripe_oauth_handle_callback($post_parm_args) {
  drupal_set_message(t('_commerce_stripe_oauth_handle_callback: called'));
  drupal_goto('<front>');
}
```

Comment: How about looking at how Drupal Commerce handles it? https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_stripe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path is wrong I think. You should be able to access that callback here.

https://mydrupalsite.com/bh_commerce_stripe_oauth/callback/randomstring

So actually your `hook_menu` should look like this.

```
/* Implements hook_menu */
function bh_commerce_stripe_oauth_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['callback'] = array(
    'title' => 'bh_commerce_stripe_oauth_callback',
    'page callback' => '_bh_commerce_stripe_oauth_handle_callback',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK     
  );
  return $items;    
}
```

Note: You don't have any path wildcards (represented by `%` in your array key) in the callback you are getting that are useful. Therefore you don't need any `page arguments`. The interesting things are in the `$_GET` (or `$_REQUEST`).

And then to access the results something like:

```
function _bh_commerce_stripe_oauth_handle_callback() {
  $scope = $_GET['scope'];
  $code = $_GET['code'];
  drupal_set_message(t('_commerce_stripe_oauth_handle_callback: called'));
  drupal_goto('<front>');
}
```